# Textbook for parton distributions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, partons

Are there any textbooks, or good pedagogical review articles, on the subject of parton distributions? I'm looking for such sources that cover all the standard topics, such as:

- Generalized parton correlation functions
- distribution functions
- distribution amplitudes
- form factors
- TMDs, and TMD factorization
- On the lattice, and other theoretical approaches
- quasi parton distributions?
- etc. etc.

Many QFT and QCD textbooks that I've seen just talk about the same select-few topics in DIS and parton distributions, like: cross-section factorization in conjunction with the OPE; bjorken-scaling at 1-loop for hadronic cross sections; DGLAP evolution in factorization scale, along with a calculation of the 1-loop splitting functions; parton distributions as light-cone correlators.

But everything else that I actually need to know for research in this area I can only find from reverse-engineering random papers that I come across — which I suppose is common in most fields in any academic discipline. It's just an overwhelming amount of information I suppose.